# Accessing value on a UnivariateSpline curve

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I'm working on a simple function to fit a curve of yields. I am using `Scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline` for the task. The function should return the value of the yield for a specific interval (maturity).

This is the simple function I have written:

```py
def curve_fit(spot_yields_df, a):
    x = spot_yields_df['INTERVAL']
    y = spot_yields_df['SPOT']

    s1 = inter.UnivariateSpline(x, y, s=0.5)

    plt.plot(x, y, marker="o", markerfacecolor='None', markersize=5, linestyle='None')
    plt.plot(x, s1(x))
    plt.show()

    return s1(a)
```

The datafrme provided as an input in the example below looks like this:

```
spot_yields_df
Out[53]: 
    CURVE_ID      ISIN    REL_DATE              SPOT   INTERVAL
0   crv_sagb  AU316223  2019-05-31  6.84543548187739   0.263014
1   crv_sagb  ED957814  2019-05-31  7.41912841796875   0.627397
2   crv_sagb  EF656651  2019-05-31  7.01629638671875   1.835616
3   crv_sagb  EJ235944  2019-05-31  7.58026123046875   3.750685
4   crv_sagb  CP507394  2019-05-31  9.12445068359375   7.564384
5   crv_sagb  EJ750004  2019-05-31  9.56756591796875  10.679452
6   crv_sagb  EI258596  2019-05-31  9.56085205078125  11.756164
7   crv_sagb  EJ750009  2019-05-31  10.1046752929688  12.843836
8   crv_sagb  EK773288  2019-05-31  10.2053833007813  15.758904
9   crv_sagb  EF556585  2019-05-31  10.2926635742188  16.846575
10  crv_sagb  EJ750019  2019-05-31  10.7022094726562  17.684932
11  crv_sagb  EK773306  2019-05-31  10.8700561523437  20.684932
12  crv_sagb  EI258592  2019-05-31  10.2859497070313  21.764384
13  crv_sagb  EJ749864  2019-05-31  10.8834838867188  24.687671
14  crv_sagb  EJ235914  2019-05-31  10.0711059570313  28.767123
```

This is the plot, which suggests the function is working well.

[image]

For example, according to the chart, s1(30) and curve_fit(spot_yields_df, 30) respectively should return a value somewhere around 10. It is returning a value around 6 instead:

```
curve_fit(spot_yields_df, 30)
Out[52]: array(6.84325277)
```

How can I return the value that corresponds to what the chart is showing. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The chart **does not show** 10 at around x=30. It shows around 10 for x=28 approximately. May be the interpolated curve drops sharply beyond x=28 and approaches 6 at x=30. Try `curve_fit(spot_yields_df, 28)` and see if it still gives you value other than approx. 10

Comment: Hi, can you copy your input DataFrame (`spot_yields_df`) into the question?

Comment: @Sheldore I said a value *around* 10 to illustrate the point. The chart definitely does not show 6.84 as the function returns.

Comment: @Sheldore `s1(28)
Out[59]: array(11.06701489)` - this is now too high, according to the chart it should return `10.25`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem isn't with the program, but with the interpolation method itself (it also means that the question is better suited to [cross-validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com), but sometimes you can't know in advance).

If you're using a smoothing factor (`s=0.5` in your case is a smoothing factor, see [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html)), the curve won't exactly hit every point in the dataset. 
 If you want it to hit every point, try setting `s=0` - in which case, the extrapolation to 30 would be a linear extrapolation from the two highest points (you can verify this). 
Alternatively, you can set `s=None` (or just don't fill a value for it, it's the default), in which case the function will choose a reasonable value for `s` - which, from running the code on my end, looks reasonable indeed (and yields a value of 9.87195):

[image]